# Determine what changed my desktop wallpaper

Tags: windows-7, virus, malware, desktop-customization, event-log

How do I determine what caused the change of my background wallpaper? Identify the programm/process if that was a malware, get event information, anything? Somehow find out why that happened.

My desktop wallpaper suddenly changed itself, to some random picture I've never seen before and I suspect this might be some malware. I scanned my PC with an antivirus but didn't find anything so I want to try to manually find what caused that.

It also added new location for that picture in the dropdown list where you select the wallpaper location, how do I remove that new option from the list?

Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my last sub-question about deleting the new custom path from the dropdown list of wallpaper locations. To do that, you need to open the Windows Registry editor (open Start menu and type `regedit` into the Run box) and go to the following key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers\Images
```

There delete all the extra values except for "Default", that will clear the list from the custom paths.

In my case I had two extra values named "ID2" and "ID3", I deleted them and that new location disappeared from the list.

Still trying to figure out what changed the wallpaper though.

Answer (score -1):

There might be many circumstances for the same.
If you used a decent antivirus then there is chance that its not caused by a malware.
(But as Windows 7 has ended support, it might be possible for some undetected virus to do the same)

Second thing, if you are a programmer, then accidently you wrote some code that caused your wallpaper to change. Its very easy to change the desktop wallpaper accidently via any programming language.

Third, you might have used or installed or applied some theme which changed the wallpaper, and its most obvious in case of windows 7.

Fourth, some programs/apps have the ability to change wallpaper purposely, and this is most commonly done by some apps that are for customization, like some floating widgets .

There can be many things that might have happened. If these weren't your cause, please post the wallpaper to some cloud and give a link here, maybe some people might know about it. Also, list the apps installed on your PC by going to Control panel >Programs > modify/uninstall apps, and post it here, may be that helps us to find the way out more accurately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry my comment accidentally got published before I fully wrote it. No, I'm not a programmer and I wasn't coding at that moment, I was just surfing the web and at some point when I minimized the windows, I noticed my wallpaper changed. I'm not sure I can upload it because it's an NSFW picture which is also an additional reason I think that was malware. At this point I disabled my internet connection and trying to identify the cause. I didn't install anything at that moment or recently, at least intentionally, neither themes nor any new software, tweaks and widgets.

Comment: Take a screen shot by pressing PrntScr button and pasting by Ctrl+V on mspaint, and then saving it as .png or .jpg, and upload it to some cloud like GDrive or DropBox, and share the link in your question. This might help us.

Comment: If you are messing up with dll files in windows API, you can change the desktop wallpaper, you might know what u are doing, but when you are indirectly communicating with the APIs, you can do it unknowingly. I'm also a programmer, and as a newbie in world of APIs, you might messup things when experimenting.

Comment: I'm also a windows programmer. Though not that much into VS n all, but I know and I've tried things regarding Win32 APIs. And its possible for a newbie to messup things. As an experienced dev, you might not face any difficulty or you might have started learning in a very suitable curve and resources, but some may go wrong at first.

Comment: If you're an experienced Windows programmer, please help me out by answering my question. You can find it on my profile regarding brightness.